# Python solution to parse Google calendar's recurrencies

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to parse GCal's recurrence field. Usually, it looks like this:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Kiev:20101111T140000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Kiev:20101111T150000
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20101112T120000Z
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Kiev
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Kiev
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
TZNAME:EEST
DTSTART:19700329T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:EET
DTSTART:19701025T040000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

I need to extract valuable for me part: event's DTSTART, DTEND, RRULE, and other iCaledar's field. 
Is there an existent solution for doing this?

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to parse the entire record, understand the format of RRULE lines, something else?

Comment: I want to parse entire record and extract event's DTSTART, DTEND, RRULE and RDATE.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the fantastic library python-dateutil (http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

Comment: I've tried this lib, but it's only iCaledar-compatible and does not understand DTEND field and other extras.

Comment: for DTEND you can use until, as rrule pararameter. ¿What other extras do you need?

Comment: @cleg: don't mistake iCalendar-the-standard (RFC 2445, now RFC 5545) with iCalendar-the-program. The calendar you show above is in iCalendar-the-format.

Comment: This is where I wound up too.  I did some simple parsing of the ical dtstart using strptime and then passed it to dateutil.rrule.rrulestr.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mxm's icalendar package:

http://codespeak.net/icalendar/

and I'm pretty sure it passes all ical fields to parsed objects. I'm not sure about reoccurence because I just don't use that in my app, but I would be surprised to find out it's not there.

Comment: Looking at that link you might think the library hasn't been updated in 4 years. More current versions can be found here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar

Answer (score 0):

As I have a similar problem and could not find anything doing the job, I've just released on pypi a small project which will not only give you the  DTSTART, DTEND, RRULE, RDATE, UID and  SUMMARY values but will also given a specific time window return all the dates that fullfill the RRULE rules.

You can get it here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyICSParser (please note I'm not at all a SW engineer so good coding practices compliance is poor and though I'll work on documentation it is still very early stage)